# How do I calculate a p-value if I have the t-statistic and d.f. (in Perl)?

Tags: perl, statistics

I have written a Perl script that performs many one-sample t-tests. I get thousands of t-statistics with their degrees of freedom (df). I need to upgrade the script to also return their p-values (there are too many to look them up manually in a table). Is there some kind of formula I can use for this with the t-statistic and d.f as input? I hope someone can help me with this, many thanks in advance!

A.A.

Comment: 1). not enough info (2). show us your coding attempt...

Comment: It's a pretty huge script. And it works fine. All I need is a formula or a piece of script that uses a t-statistic and it's d.f. (which I both already calculated and stored into memory) to calculate a p-value.. :-)
But if there is something specific you would like to know about the script, I would gladly supply you with the information.

Comment: There is no way to tell what you want/need without more information.

Comment: @Mitch, Brad: What additional info is needed? As elbenshira says, Abdel needs a subroutine to integrate the area under the probability distribution function for the t distribution, from the value of the statistic to infinity. I think the problem is well-specified.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using [Statistics::Distributions](https://metacpan.org/pod/Statistics::Distributions) seems pretty straightforward:

```
print Statistics::Distributions::tprob($dof,$tstat);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot u guys! I really appreciate all your help. I think bubaker's answer is the one I needed!

Answer (score 6):

A search of MetaCPAN reveals the following:

https://metacpan.org/pod/Statistics::Distributions

Answer (score 3):

If you are doing a two-tailed test, then your p-value = 2*P(T > t), where t is your calculated test statistic. So essentially, you need a way to model the T-dist in order to integrate(T-dist from t to INFINITY). Here is a demo: http://www.stat.tamu.edu/~west/applets/tdemo.html

I'm not familiar with Perl and its libraries, but hopefully this gets you started. You can write a rudimentary integrator and check some values to make sure that it is accurate enough.

Comment: FWIW, I think this is the best answer... :)